# Why EAF browser is opening outside emacs buffer?

Tags: init-file, window, web-browser

I'm new to emacs, so excuse any naivety that you might see.

These are my sys and emacs config.

```
System Version: macOS 12.5 (21G72)
GNU Emacs 28.1
```

I've tried installing eaf and eaf-browser in emacs, i followed the demo in the [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/emacs-eaf/emacs-application-framework),
and supposedly it was installed correctly ( supposedly because it still showing this error in the minibuffer each time i lunch emacs
`Please install app-frontmost from https://pypi.org/project/mac-app-frontmost/ to make EAF works with macOS platform.` !!! even thought i have the specific package installed.)
this is my config in `init.el`:

```
(use-package eaf
  :load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/emacs-application-framework"
  :custom
  ; See https://github.com/emacs-eaf/emacs-application-framework/wiki/Customization
  (eaf-browser-continue-where-left-off t)
  (eaf-browser-enable-adblocker t)
  (browse-url-browser-function 'eaf-open-browser)
  :init
  (require 'eaf-image-viewer)
  (require 'eaf-pdf-viewer)
  (require 'eaf-browser)
  (require 'eaf-markdown-previewer)
  (require 'eaf-jupyter)
  :config
  (defalias 'browse-web #'eaf-open-browser)
  (eaf-bind-key scroll_up "C-n" eaf-pdf-viewer-keybinding)
  (eaf-bind-key scroll_down "C-p" eaf-pdf-viewer-keybinding)
  (eaf-bind-key nil "M-q" eaf-browser-keybinding)) ;; unbind, see more in the Wiki
(require 'eaf-browser)
(require 'eaf-pdf-viewer)
```

when i try to lunch `eaf-open-browser` actually the browser lunches but in a separate window outside emacs.
I have no idea why is that ? would appreciate some insights .

I though that's maybe the default behaviour and should be customized in order to open the browser in the same window, so i check the customization section in EAF github repo and found no mentioning of that plus i've watched some videos in youtube and saw that actually the default behaviour for eaf-browser is to open in the same window as emacs.

**EDIT:**
turns out the weird behaviour happens only when i enter full screen with emacs. when not ! the eaf-browser buffer actually stays in emacs window.

Comment: I have no idea, but I remember opening a similar issue for Ubuntu [here](https://github.com/emacs-eaf/emacs-application-framework/issues/632). Maybe there is relevant information for you there.

Comment: thanks i followed your issue and opened an issue for osx , and it turns out it's actually a known bug in the program. if anyone with the same config faces the same issue a work around could be found here https://macowners.club/posts/using-xwidgets-on-macos/